# Query takes so long in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 models called `stores`, `customers`, `subscriptions`.

`subscription` has two foreign keys from store and customer models and also has start_date and end_date.

The tables are pretty simple. store only has id and name same as customers.

I'm running this query.

```
SELECT subscription_subscription.store_id, COUNT(*) AS sub_store
FROM subscription_subscription 
WHERE CURRENT_DATE() <= subscription_subscription.end_date
GROUP BY subscription_subscription.store_id 
ORDER BY sub_store DESC
```

And here it is: `621760 total, Query took 9.6737 seconds.`

All of tables have 1 million rows.

But when I remove the `WHERE CURRENT_DATE() <= subscription_subscription.end_date` query takes `0.3177 seconds`.

How can I optimize date comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these two things:

> 1. use a variable to store `CURRENT_DATE()` and use this variable in query instead of function
> 2. Create an `index` on `end_date` which includes `store_id`

Comment: variable didn't help but index worked for me. thanks.

Comment: *use a variable to store CURRENT_DATE() and use this variable in query instead of function* Makes no sense - this is a constant which is evaluated during execution plan building, i.e. before query execution.